# How to set demarcation items on range slider in angular 4

Tags: angularjs

**I am working on range slider in angular 4,I have to include demarcation items in range slider,Can any one help ?** 
I am using attributes like below,But its not working 
data-grid:"false" ;
data-grid-num :10

If you have any example code please post here .

Comment: Hi if any one have a range slider example code with responsive at least angular 2 ,Please post here

Comment: Please add some demo examples!

Comment: if range silder is required the check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ion-range-slider